# Handling a literal space in a filename

Tags: python, linux, file, space

I have problem with `os.access(filename, os.R_OK)` when file is an absolute path on a Linux system with space in the filename. I have tried many ways of quoting the space, from `"'" + filename + "'" to filename.replace(' ', '\\ ')` but it doesn't work.

How can I escape the filename so my shell knows how to access it? In terminal I would address it as `'/home/abc/LC\ 1.a'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to (and shouldn't) escape the space in the file name. When you are working with a command line shell, you need to escape the space because that's how the shell tokenizes the command and its arguments. Python, however, is expecting a file name, so if the file name has a space, you just include the space.